# Submit Button with multiple fieldsets on one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, submit, http-post, fieldset

I have a view that has the ultimate aim of being a user creation form. It is structured in the following way:

```
<fieldset>
@Html.DropDownList("first dropdown")
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="exists">
@Html.DropDownList("seconddropdown")
@Html.DropDownList("third dropdown")
@Html.DropDownList("fourth dropdown")
<input type="submit" value="Create User"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="new">
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown")
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown")
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown")
<input type="submit" value="Create User"/>
</fieldset>

<script>
//script here shows and hides fieldsets depending on value chosen in first dropdown
</script>
```

Depening on the value chosen in the first dropdown, either fieldset exist or fieldset new will show. they both interact with the database differently so I really need to be able to handle the submit action separately for each. I have tried creating a submit within each fieldset, but the controller action is never hit.

I am obviously missing the mark with MVC submit buttons so could anyone help me understand how these work and how to create multiple (and separate) submit possibilities on one view.

Many thanks

Comment: No `using(Html.BeginForm) {` or any `<form>` tag. Is that just not copied in your sample, or really missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You could have two forms, each that post to a different action...the submit will then only submit the form values in that form...

e.g.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset id="exists">
@Html.DropDownList("seconddropdown")
@Html.DropDownList("third dropdown")
@Html.DropDownList("fourth dropdown")
<input type="submit" value="Log in"/>
</fieldset>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset id="new">
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown")
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown")
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown")
<input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</fieldset>
}
```